# Making a Reqeust class in kotlin with Volley

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a general Request class with kotlin, which I can use to make Request with Volley.

The problem I'm having is that I can not return the response of the Request.

I'm trying to get the response of the request so that I can proces the data.

I can't seem to find a good source which describes how to make a Helper class for making Request

Request class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class Request(var context: Context, var url: String) {

    var response : String? = null

    fun makePOSTRequest() {

        val requestQueue: RequestQueue? = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST, url,
            Response.Listener { response ->

            }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.i("Error", "[" + error + "]")
            }) {

            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                return params
            }

        }

        requestQueue?.add(stringRequest)

    }

    fun makeGETRequest() {

        val requestQueue: RequestQueue? = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener { response ->

                println(response) // Response: {"message":"ok","locaties"[{"id":"739","name":"Company","code":"","klant":"Client"}]}


               this.response = response // Here I'm trying to fill the response var



            }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.i("Error", "[" + error + "]")
            }) {
        }

        requestQueue?.add(stringRequest)

    }


}
```

Implementation

```
var request = context?.let { Request(it, BuildConfig.API_URL + "getLocatiesLijst.php?name=" + bdl?.getString("name")) }

        request?.makeGETRequest()

        var response = request?.response

        println(response) // This give Null back
```

Comment: Volley performs requests asynchronously  , You should to have a call back listener , some thing like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47674776/6478047 . Its old but idea is something similar

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that request is async, but when you run this come, println("") will be called immediately. You should wait for a result.
You can add some callback to the listener or try to use coroutines.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I did some research on coroutines and found a solution. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have been busy with implementing a request helper class with coroutines. And I think I have found a solution to my own problem. I'm using coroutines to make the request async.

[Source of solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486087/how-can-i-use-coroutines-with-volley-so-that-my-code-can-be-written-like-sychron)

Request.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import kotlin.coroutines.*;

class Request(var context: Context, var url: String) {

    suspend fun makeGetRequest() = suspendCoroutine<String> { cont ->
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                cont.resume("Response is: ${response}")
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { cont.resume("Something went wrong!") })

        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }

}
```

Implementation

```
class LocationFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {

     protected lateinit var job: Job
     override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
                get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        var rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_list, container, false)

        //TODO doe verzoek voor lijst van locaties

        val bdl = arguments

        var request = context?.let { Request(it, BuildConfig.API_URL + "getLocatiesLijst.php?name=" + bdl?.getString("name")) }

         job = Job()

         launch {
             val data = request?.makeGetRequest()
             println(data)
         }
    }
```

Result

> I/System.out: Response is:{"message":"ok","locaties":[{"id":"739","name":"Company","lce_code":"code","klant":"Client"}]}

Comment: Nice, but never do such things in UI classes. Use at least ViewModels